# Relative Frequencies and distributions

Tags: statistics

i have calculated the relative frequencies for some coefficients and nearly all of them are in the intervall 0,9..1,00.

Now two questions:
a) would it be better to filter the data and just work with the data over a specific thresolds
b) depending on the answer of question a) which would be a possible distribution?

i would like to show the picture but may not yet :-(

But you can try to imagine the way, that i have 10 classes with band with = 0.1 and more than 95% are in the last one from 0.9 to 1.0.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Comment:

The beta family of distributions has support $(0,1)$ and so is
frequently used to model proportions. Depending on the parameters
chosen, there is a vast variety of possible shapes of distributions
in this family. Roughly speaking, the first shape parameter, often
denoted $\alpha > 0$ governs the shape of the density function near 0;
the larger the parameter the 'flatter' the curve near 0. The second
shape parameter $\beta > 0$ governs the shape of the density function near 1.
The mean of the distribution is $\alpha/(\alpha + \beta).$ You can
read details and see graphs in the Wikipedia article 'beta distribution'.

From what you say, it seems possible that a member of the beta
family with $\alpha$ large and $\beta$ small might fit your data.
Below is the histogram of 10,000 observations simulated according
to $Beta(20, .5),$ along with the density function of that distribution.

[image]

Only about 4% of the probability under this density curve lies below 0.9.

---

Computer code from R statistical software, used for the above:

```
 x = rbeta(10^4, 20, .5)  # generte fake data
 hist(x, br=20, prob=T, col="wheat")
 curve(dbeta(x, 20, .5), lwd=2, col="blue", add=T)
 pbeta(.9, 20, .5)
 ## 0.04132748  # P(X < .9) = .041
```

Comment: Good morning. Thank you very much. My histogramm looks pretty similiar to your one so it seems to be that a beta function pretty good will fit my needs or to say it more correct: it will fit my distribution. The main issue i have is that my data results from some coefficients which shows the similiarity of some data and many of them are 1 so a last question to you (or the team) if it is still correct to model it by such a distribution or generally by a distribution at all ?

Comment: I guess you may be talking about something like the 'coefficient of determination' measuring linear association of two pairs of scores. If that is a 'statistic' derived from randomly sampled data, then it has a sampling distribution (which may vary from one population to another). Reasonable to try to infer characteristics of such a sampling distribution. I would have to know more about the data, the 'coefficient', the purpose of your work, etc., in order to give the best advice.

Comment: Hello Bruce, many thanks for coming back and give me the chance to go more in detail: it is a study about how "similiar" two database fields are regards the text in that field. I.e. i compare the field from database A to the database B. I have devided to calculated the bigram (dice coefficient) which is in the intervall [0;1] and as you maybe know it is 1.0 if the textes are equal. so i have analysed more than 800 textes and most of them got a 1.0 but some <1.0. This results (i have generated a histogram) i would like to "transform" to the proper distribution