# Probability distribution with data in [0;1] close to 1

Tags: probability

Good morning!

I have already posted a question similiar to the following one but the main question of this post is slightly different so i decided to open a new question regards to this.

Basically i have several measurement data which are in the interval [0;1] and most of them are close to 1 or really one. The data itself results from a coefficient which calculates the similarity so 1 means equal.
I have used for this the so called dice coefficient (n-gram similarity)..

With the help of the forum we came to result a beta distribution will fit the needs.

The main concern i have is the fact that many data are exactly 1 so i am not sure if i will run into trouble or will make an error i am not aware about for now.

Due some complains about my questions i try to specify more:
The following example shall make it more clear:

data intervall . number of data

[0,0 - 0,1]  : 1
]0,1 - 0,2]  : 1
]0,2 - 0,3]  : 1
]0,3 - 0,4]  : 1
]0,4 - 0,5]  : 1
]0,5 - 0,6]  : 1
]0,6 - 0,7]  : 1
]0,7 - 0,8]  : 1
]0,8 - 0,9]  : 1
]0,9 - 1,0]  : 91

From the 91 please take as an example

[0,90 - 0,91]  : 5
]0,91 - 0,92]  : 5
]0,92 - 0,93]  : 5
]0,93 - 0,94]  : 5
]0,94 - 0,95]  : 5
]0,95 - 0,96]  : 5
]0,96 - 0,97]  : 5
]0,97 - 0,98]  : 5
]0,98 - 0,99]  : 5
]0,99 - 1,00]  : 46

So you see a lot of them are eqaul to 1...and this concerns me or to say
it with other words "i am not sure to make a methodical error"

The Beta distrubtion could fit but if yes do i have to consider sth in detail?
or better use another one?

Any tips, hints will be appreciatly.

Thx
Mel

Comment: Can you post the link to the other question, just to add context to this one...

Comment: of course: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1903153/relative-frequencies-and-distributions

Comment: MATLAB function https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/betafit.html&ved=0ahUKEwjmhoCFrvvOAhUEtxQKHTSwA-8QFggbMAA&usg=AFQjCNHHDymVzMRtIm-rmlHpEctFx3VgOw&sig2=vN_O1RLuLBI0yE4708nD4A "moves" the value of the samples at 1 of the minimum representable foat to the left before fitting.

Comment: Gents, any idea? or some hints? Hopefully i have updated the questions the way it is easier to understand